# Links to uploaded Files are diffrent to the upload Folder (open atrium)

Tags: media

If I upload Files throuth the Uploadfunction in the edit subspace section (doesn't matter if subspace or mainspace), It loads the picture in the

```
\sites\default\files\private
```

or

```
\sites\default\files
```

folder.

Depending where I want to upload the pictures. But they are not shown on the Site. So if I right-click the image-icon, I get different path to the pictures.

**for example :**

```
system/files/styles/panopoly_image_original/private/logo_lang_80x24.png?itok=BfifKC1c
```

but the files are in the other folders.

How can i fix it?